# Getting 'gradlew.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. while building react native project

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradlew, gradle-wrapper

[image]

Getting this error while building up the react native project
'gradlew.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat tasks
'gradlew.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

This Project is working fine for me in Mac Machine not working in Windows Machine

Answer (score 0):

The Terminal that is integrated into Android Studio is a PowerShell terminal. You can see that by the `PS` at the beginning of the line.

In PowerShell commands work a bit different that the old cmd.exe command line shell. For programs not in PATH, like `gradlew.bat` that is located in your current directory, you have to specify the path when executing it.

Therefore eyon have to execute

```
.\gradlew.bat
```

Alternatively a forward slash also works:

```
./gradlew.bat
```

For shorten the command you can omit the `.bat` ending.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to build the app using npx react-native run-android command and Im unable to understand why it is showing gradle error

Comment: @TejpreetSingh then please update your question and describe that. Include the command(s) you execute and the error output as text and format it as code (no screenshot).

Comment: Thanks @Robert for your suggestion I will definitely do that.